# SwiftUI NavigationLink does not reset views positions

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a simple VStack with views inside. When the keyboard appears, the views are moving up.

But when I click on a NavigationLink when the keyboard is still showing, and I go back, the views are stuck in their previous position, pretending the keyboard is still here.

I would be happy to have any solution

before and after

[image: before]
[image: after]

[image: GIF]

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.systemGroupedBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        VStack {
            LogoView()
                .padding(.vertical, 50)
            if isSigningUp {
                SignUpView()
            } else {
                SignInView()
            }
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("Don't have an account ?")
                Button(action: {
                    isSigningUp.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("\(invertedAuthCaseLabel) !").foregroundColor(Color("mainColor"))
                }
            }
        }.padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: 500)
    }
}
```

I tried the `.ignoringSafeArea(.keyboard)` modifier but it didn't work, my views were still moving.

Answer (score 0):

if you think the culprit here is keyboard, then you can force the keyboard to close in [onDisappear(action:_)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/ondisappear(perform:)). The following code might help you close the keyboard.

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :(
Navigation is triggered before keyboard can dismiss.